# How to add .c and .h files to Atmel Studio 6?

Tags: ide, header-files, atmel

I know there are a lot of questions on this topic, and I've looked through a fair number of them. However I am still having problems.

I started writing a test program for a prototype PCB, and now that it's grown to nearly 1000 lines I'm trying to break it up into libraries that I can use for particular functions.

I thought this would be very simple. Make .c and .h files for each library that I need. I.e. I would have OLED.h and OLED.c for functions that control an OLED display. Copy the appropriate functions/definitions into each file. Then copy these files into the solution in Atmel Studio. I put them into the src folder under the project name.

However, this doesn't work! I get an exceedingly long list of errors. All of the things that are defined in the .h file are apparently undefined as far as the compiler is concerned. I also get many error messages of the type "unknown type name int16_t/uint16_t/uint8_t/etc..." That part is really baffling to me. Why should it matter that functions are in an external library, now the compiler doesn't understand what those data types mean?

So, this is probably a stupid problem to have. I don't want Atmel Studio to control my libraries by wrapping them up in some "library project" or somethig, I want to put them in a folder of my choosing and add them when I need them. I've searched for answers to this problem and I find long tutorials about changing the compiler settings for the project, the linker settings, etc... I tried this tutorial and still no dice: http://www.engblaze.com/tutorial-using-avr-studio-5-with-arduino-projects/#setup

I also can't find a way to add something by right clicking the project and clicking "Add." It wants me to find .a files. The "Add Library" dialog box in Atmel Studio is awful, it seems.

Surely it can't be that convoluted to just add a library to an existing project and have it function normally?! I've used PICs in the past and coming to Atmel I've found horrible documentation and a weird super-slick super-fly whizz bang interface that can't leave well enough alone and obfuscates simple function. What can I do to add these libraries?

**UPDATE:** Seemed to answer my own question. Turns out I needed to include all of the libraries to recognize data types and whatnot into the .c file. I somehow assumed this only had to be done in the main file but obviously I was mistaken. Adding asf.h seems to work well as it includes all of the MCU specific port definitions/names and all of that. All good for now!

Answer (score 3):

Adding library files to a solution should be simple. Go to the Solution Explorer, right-click on your solution, and go to "Add->Existing Item". If you want to add a pre-existing library and keep it in a separate folder from your solution, click the arrow next to "Add" and choose "Add as link". That saves many headaches due to having a duplicate copy of your library in your solution folder, and files not staying up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in saying that you need to include the necessary header files in the `.c` files where they are used.

The compiler compiles each C file separately, and then links them together at the end, so you got the error `unknown typename int_*` because the compiler had not seen the relevant header in the context of compiling that C file.

You also seem to be in some confusion as to the difference between definition and declaration.

A function is:

- *Declared* in the header file. This means there is a function prototype, e.g. `int some_func(char some_var);` which tells the compiler that the function exists, but does not tell it *what it is*. This is necessary because the compiler only looks at one C file at a time, so needs to be told that other functions exist.
- *Defined* in the C file.This is the actual function body, i.e. `int some_func(char some_var) { do_stuff(some_var); }`. After compilation of each individual C file in isolation, the *linker* is called to put all the pieces together and give you your final binary, which you flash to the device.

A function can be (and must be) defined only once, but may be declared many times - even in the same file, so long as the declarations are not conflicting.