# Adding standard C library files to Atmel Studio

Tags: c, avr, atmega, atmel, atmelstudio

I have Atmel Studio installed on my system, but when I want to use for example time.h of the stdio, it tells me the library does not exist!
So I downloaded this library: 
http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/avr-libc/

Now, how can I include the whole library in my project?

After extracting, there are individual .h files and .c files that I can add in libc and include folders, but I'd like to add them all to my project (at least all of stdio, time, string...).

Thanks

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How to add .c and .h files to Atmel Studio 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955806/how-to-add-c-and-h-files-to-atmel-studio-6). However, that one lacks an accepted answer.

Comment: Not a dup. The thing is, I don't know which file in the folder I downloaded to include in the project that would add all those headers(stdio, time, string...) to the project

Comment: The link I posted contains details on how to do that.

Comment: dude!! I simply want to add ALL libraries in the "avr-libc-2.0.0" folder I downloaded to be included in my project with addition of one .h or binday or .a file or whatever, not having to go around and add ten .h and ten .c files!

Comment: That's why I redirected you to the link above. I'm by no means an expert in these topics, so I'm sorry, but I can't be of any further help to you regarding your problem.